# Unity3D: Launch local documentation from unity 2018.2.5

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I install Unity 2018.2.5, copy offline documentation zip in `C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data` and unzip it. When i open Unity3D and clic in *Help > Unity Manual*, it launchs web documentation references instead of local documentation. Previous versions (2018.1.2) had worked. How solve this in order to launch local documentation? Thanks and sorry for my english.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you already have "Visual Studio Tools for unity" plugin installed. If not this is the first thing you should do. If you already have it or you have installed but still have the issue described in your question, do the following:

**1**.It seems like you downloaded the documentation manually from [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/OfflineDocumentation.html). Don't do this. Let Unity download it for you.

Run the Unity installer again but only select documentation this time. It will install the documentation to the current version of Unity.

[image]

Restart Visual Studio and check if it's working. If there is still an issue, follow step *#2*.

**2**.From Visual Studio go the *Tools* ---> *Option* menu.

Now, go to *Tools For Unity* then manually enter the path of the documentation you unzipped in the *Preferred Unity Installation* box then click "OK". Restart Visual Studio.

[image]

Comment: I'm using **vs code** because **visual studio 2017** size is bigger and internet is too slow. Is there any plugin for **vs code**?

Comment: Sorry I don't know. I don't use VS Code. You just have to download VS once and that's it. The installer makes it easier to download it even with slow internet.